# Elasticsearch geo distance filter on a point type geo shape

Tags: elasticsearch

So I have a location field in my documents (posts). This location field is a geo shape. It could be a point or a polygon. Sometimes I may have to use geo distance filter to get posts tagged closest to some coordinate (only posts with `point` type geo shape not polygons). However, on attempting to use the geo_distance filter I encountered the following error.

```
... nested: QueryParsingException[[naya] failed to find geo_point field [location]]; }] ...',
```

Is there a way to use geo_distance filter on geo shapes that are `point` type?

Comment: I don't think so. From the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/geo-shapes.html): "Geo-shapes cannot be used to caculate distance, cannot be used for sorting or scoring, and cannot be used in aggregations."

Comment: @AndreiStefan Any possibility of combining the query with this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/querying-geo-shapes.html ?

Comment: Could you check if my answer worked for you? If not, did you find another solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "geo_shape": {
      "location": {
        "shape": {
          "type": "circle",
          "radius": "100km",
          "coordinates": [ 
            77,
            28
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use the coordinates of the centre from where you want to run the geo-distance query. Use a shape like a circle, with a specified radius.
It matches any intersecting shapes as well as any geo-points lying within the shape you provided in the query.

Comment: Yes but cannot filter by distance. your query works if you want to find what lies within a circle but to filter by distance (promote closer ones) geo_shape is only viable with custom script. I am using a custom decay script.